# Audience Manager event system conflicting with DXA

Tags: dxa, audience-manager

We have recently installed DXA into an existing Tridion 2013 SP1 solution as a parallel Blueprint structure completely separate from the previously existing one but within the same CM instance.

While running the installation powershell script referenced [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA) we had errors related to the default Audience Manager event system code running on the system, but completed the install by disabling this code temporarily. However, now we are seeing the same error in the CM whenever we try to make any changes pertaining to publications, from changing a name to creating a new publication. 
The error is:

> The following BluePrint conflicts have been found: The Segment with Uri 'tcm:2066-1-198656' (*segment name*) is in a shared Folder that would be removed. The Segment with Uri 'tcm:2066-4-198656' (*segment name*) is in a shared Folder that would be removed. The Segment with Uri 'tcm:2066-5-198656' (*segment name*) is in a shared Folder that would be removed. The Segment with Uri 'tcm:2066-6-198656' (*segment name*) is in a shared Folder that would be removed. The Segment with Uri 'tcm:2066-7-198656' (*segment name*) is in a shared Folder that would be removed. The Segment with Uri 'tcm:2066-8-198656' (*segment name*) is in a shared Folder that would be removed. The Segment with Uri 'tcm:2066-12-198656' (*segment name*) is in a shared Folder that would be removed.

Note: I've removed the segment names from the error for client privacy and replaced them with *segment name*.

This blocks us from setting up our new DXA Blueprint structure unless we once again disable the Audience Manager Event System DLL, which I don't view as a long term solution. The segments listed are from the previously existing Blueprint structure and are not replicated in our DXA installation.

As mentioned, temporarily disabling the Tridion.AudienceManagement.ContentManagerEvents.dll allows us to update our publications. Is this a known issue with DXA and Audience Manager, and if so, does anyone have a solution beyond this temporary disable?

Comment: Did you also create a copy of the AM database? Or are you trying to use the same AM database in both CM instances?

Comment: We are not planning to use AM on our microsites at this time, so no new database.

Comment: So you pointed it to the same AM database? That's your problem, then. The AM and CM databases need to be in sync so you cannot use the AM database for multiple CM instances.

Comment: Unless...did you also re-use the same CM database? I initially thought you created a new environment (since you said you ran the database scripts) but re-reading the question it sounds like you just added a new BluePrint to an existing CM instance (and therefore use the same, existing CM database too). Could you elaborate?

Comment: We did install it in the same CM with the same CM DB. We first saw the error when running the script referenced here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: Ah okay - well that should have worked then. The problem with "temporarily disabling the Tridion.AudienceManagement.ContentManagerEvents.dll" is that it can cause this kind of issue. If you modify the BluePrint structure while that is disabled, AM won't know about the changes. Normally it can automatically recover from that, but apparently not in this case. If you keep it disabled, you're just making the problem worse. So we need to sort out your AM database, but I'm not sure if that is something we can accomplish easily here...

Comment: I'm curious about the error you got when running the `cms-import.ps1` script (importing into a separate BluePrint); I wouldn't expect similar errors in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a call and looked at this issue together. It turns out that DXA is only coincidentally involved.

What happened was that a restore was done of the databases, from Production to Development. But the Audience Manager database was not included in that restore (only CM and CD databases). As a result, the AM database pointed to Publication IDs that were no longer valid - and in some cases pointed to completely different Publications now. That led to it being confused about where the AM Folders and Segments belonged and being unable to apply the BluePrint changes due to conflicts.

The fix was to also restore the AM database from Production, so that it was in sync with the CM database again. That's the lesson to take away from this: if you restore your CM database, you better restore your AM database too (especially when restoring across DTAP).